# Data can not be synchronized using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I store a data in a factory like this:

```
module.factory('AddedStockListData', function(){
var list= [];
var size = 0;
return{
    getList: function(){
        return list;
    },
    setList: function(data){
        list = data;
    },
    getSize:function(){
        return size;
    },
    setSize:function(){
        size++;
    },
    setDelSize:function(){
        size--;
    }
}
});
```

And in my controller the code as follows:

```
    $scope.stocksSearchList = AddedStockListData.getList();

   $scope.load = function($done){        
    $timeout(function() { 
        document.getElementById("showTipsToDropDown").style.display = "none";
        $scope.stocksSearchList = AddedStockListData.getList();
        $done();
    }, 500); 

}
```

My html like this:

```
<ons-page ng-controller="createPortStockController">
    <ons-pull-hook ng-action="load($done)" var="loader" id="pullDown">
        <span ng-switch="loader.getCurrentState()">
          <span ng-switch-when="initial"><ons-icon size="35px" icon="ion-arrow-down-a"></ons-icon> Pull down to refresh</span>
          <span ng-switch-when="preaction"><ons-icon size="35px" icon="ion-arrow-up-a"></ons-icon> Release to refresh</span>
          <span ng-switch-when="action"><ons-icon size="35px" spin="true" icon="ion-load-d"></ons-icon> Loading data...</span>
        </span>
    </ons-pull-hook>
    <div>
        <ons-toolbar class="DCF"  fixed-style>
            <div class="left">
                <ons-back-button style="color:white;"></ons-back-button>
            </div> 
            <div class="center" style="font-size:22px;" >Create Portfolio</div>
            <div ng-click="create()"class="right" style="font-size:18px;color:white;margin-top:10px;padding-right:10px;" >Create</div>
        </ons-toolbar>
        <div class="addStockButton" ng-click = "myNavigator.pushPage('portStockSearchList.html', { animation : 'slide'})">
            <i class="fa fa-plus" ></i>Add Stock
            <p id="showTipsToDropDown"style="margin:0px;font-size:12px;text-align:center;color:#adadad;">After your first time add stocks, please drop down to refresh</p>
        </div>

        <div class="stockSearchList">
            <div ng-repeat="stockSearch in stocksSearchList">
                <div class="stockSearchOne">
                    <div class="stockSearchOneComp">{{stockSearch.company}}</div>
                    <div class="stockSearchOneInfo">Symbol: {{stockSearch.symbol}} | Exchange:{{stockSearch.exchange}} </div>                        
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Actually, I change the factory data in next page,I want to make this page change the display while the factory data is changed.
But the result is , at the first time I change the data in the next page and back to this page, the data will not display, and I will refresh this page by use the ons-pull-hook> and then if I go to the next page to change the data, when I back to here, data will be synchronized display .
So the result is at the first time , I have to refresh the page to get the data, but after the first time, I don't need to do this

Anybody can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$scope.$apply()` after the data have been fetched, it should update the content without any need to refresh the page. You can learn more about `$scope.$apply()` [here](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html).

Comment: I do not know how to do this.because the data have been fetched at the next page, actually in the other controller.